# reCAPTCHA doesn't render when placed in certain places on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, recaptcha

I'm trying to add a reCAPTCHA to WooCommerce Checkout on WordPress. When I use the following snippet the captcha loads and works correctly:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'woocommerce_checkout_recaptcha_field' );

function woocommerce_checkout_recaptcha_field( ) {
    echo '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>';
}
```

However as soon as I move it next to the terms and conditions checkbox:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions', 'woocommerce_checkout_recaptcha_field' );

function woocommerce_checkout_recaptcha_field( ) {
    echo '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>';
}
```

The captcha stops loading. I can see the captcha beginning to load as the page makes a gap for it but then after a split second it disappears again.

Anyone got any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197121/woocommerce-checkout-not-working-with-no-captcha-recaptcha-for-woocommerce-plugi : The plugin is just written to protect the Woocommerce Registration and Login, not the Checkout Process. You use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-captcha-recaptcha-for-woocommerce/ ?

Comment: My code is working but for some reason when I simply change the action position in some places it loads and others it doesn't. The div is definitely being inserted in all cases.